# How to draw a table with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vector

I need to draw a table of data into a vector image with C#. I'm looking a library or component that helps me to draw the table without having to care about its layout myself.

All I'd like to care about is what data belongs into which cell.

I already know of some libraries that allow me to create vector images with C# (e.g. SharpVectorGraphics/SvgNet for SVG images), but I can't find anything that helps me with the table.

#### Question

Does anybody know of a library or component that can do this? It doesn't have to be free if it does the job well. The vector image should have a format that can be displayed by a standard installation of Microsoft PowerPoint and Word.

#### Question #2:

Does anybody know a way to render (an) HTML (table) to an image with C#?

Comment: Drawing a table with data sounds like a simple enough task to do for yourself using one of the mentioned frameworks.

Comment: It's not that simple to make it look good (e.g. overflowing columns, automatically determining row heights / column widths etc.).. But that's what I finally had to do - although I still hope to find a library as my solution has some uncovered and ugly edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [aspose;](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/key-features.aspx) if no one else comes up with a better solution for you. It would do as you ask, but it doesn't "feel" like a good solution!

- Create a Word Document in memory
- Add a Table
- Populate that table
- Export to an Image.

Hopefully someone comes up with something better! :(

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways of solving this.

[Drawing:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287522%28VS.71%29.aspx)
You can littery draw your table and content using C#, this way would off course be a large investment in time but would proberbly be the fastest and most profensional way of doing it.

[Print to picture](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0460__GUI-Windows-Forms/PrintBMPimage.htm)
A bit simular to what others have suggested, make the HTML code for what you want, and throw it into a WebBrowser Consol. Then do a print preview to a bitmap.